# Renaming an external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs

I have a 1tb wd Passport named My Passport. I want to rename it to get rid of the space.
I tried using [the last opetion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=782537) offered here. However, I encounter the following error:

> Error setting label: Command-line `ntfslabel "/dev/sdb1" "MyPassport"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Volume is scheduled for check.
>   Please boot into Windows TWICE, or use the 'force' option.
>   NOTE: If you had not scheduled check and last time accessed this volume
>   using ntfsmount and shutdown system properly, then init scripts in your
>   distribution are broken. Please report to your distribution developers
>   (NOT to us!) that init scripts kill ntfsmount or mount.ntfs-fuse during
>   shutdown instead of proper umount.
>    (udisks-error-quark, 0)

I have no idea what to do...

I tried the following: `ntfslabel --force "/dev/sdb1" "MyPassport"` but apparently, I mistook on the usage of ntfslabel:

> ```
> Usage: ntfslabel [options] device [label]
>     -n, --no-action    Do not write to disk
>     -f, --force        Use less caution
>         --new-serial   Set a new serial number
>         --new-half-serial Set a partial new serial number
>     -q, --quiet        Less output
>     -v, --verbose      More output
>     -V, --version      Display version information
>     -h, --help         Display this help
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the drive formatted in ntfs mode? Try this

```
sudo mkntfs -f /dev/sdb1 && sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 MyPassport
```

**Warning**: `mkntfs -f` performs a fast format leading to data loss!!!

Comment: however, it seems to be working on my computer only. When I try to plug it to another, I get a bus error telling me an operation is pending...

Comment: and... all the data were erased...